# TikZ: How to draw a niveau set of a function?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a function F with two variable x and y and I like to illustrate the sets $F^(-1)(c)$. My idea is to colour the domain $[-2,2]x[-2,2]$ depending on the value of the function at that point.

I used two loops and tried to consider small squared and fill them with different colours. But there are two problems. First, I reached very fast the memory limit. Second, I could not choose the colour depending on the function value.

The function ist $F(x,y)=x^2+(1-x)^3y^2$ and I computed that the image of the domain is $[0,112]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, up to the function, an exact copy of the example on page 162 of the pgfplots manual. (texdoc pgfplots)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    title={$x^2+(1-x)^3\cdot y^2$},
    domain=-2:2,
    view={0}{90},
    colorbar horizontal,
]
\addplot3 [
        contour filled={
            number=14,
        },
    ] {x^2+(1-x)^3*y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]